# Desire2Learn authentication from LTI to Valence

Tags: desire2learn, lti

Given an LTI request, how does one authenticate to the Valence API?

The only thing that I have seen is this:

[Widgets and APIs in Desire2Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524572/widgets-and-apis-in-desire2learn)

This seems to indicate that when our External Learning Tool receives a POST 
from the D2L server, that we can then issue a Valence API authentication 
request, which is a GET of the form:

"https://{server domain}/d2l/auth/api/token?x_a={app id}&x_b={unencoded redirect url signed with app key}&x_target={encoded redirect url}"

whereupon the D2L server will immediately return a response of the form:

{redirect url}?x_a={token id}&x_b={token key}&x_c={user identity signature}

without requesting credentials from the user.  My questions are:

If this is correct, how does the D2L server identify the user for which authentication 
is being requested, since no user information is specified in the request?

Is there some kind of session information that must be appended to the authentication request url, or that must accompany it in the form of cookies?

If the description above is not correct, how does the External Learning Tool authenticate with the Valence API, given an LTI request?

Answer (score 0):

The automatic redirection only occurs in the scenario of a calling back in from BLTI or from a Widget. This is enabled by the fact that the browser still has a session for the logged in user (as maintained by session cookies).

A standalone app arriving to the system may not have that session and will go through credential prompts.

Two additional notes:
-you can retrieve information on the logged in user with the call "whoami" 
-users will get a prompt when they first use an application asking if they want the app to access data on their behalf.

**Update:**
I have put a [basic sample](http://code.google.com/p/desire2learn-valence/downloads/detail?name=BLTIValence.zip) together showing LTI and Valence and done a [quick blog post to describe it in more detail](http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2012/06/05/blti-and-valence-sample/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working as described on a 9.4.1 server hosted with D2L.

Comment: I now have a LTI auth function that tracks and exposes session cookies.  One problem I see with tracking the cookies is that we don't always perform an LTI auth when we need one - we save the LTI token and reuse it.  When reusing an LTI token there are no session cookies to pass to the Valence auth process.  We could save them along with the token info and try to reuse them, but they would most likely be invalid when used with some other session, even when it is okay to reuse the token.

Comment: If the cookies are really required for LTI-Valence auth transfer, then it is possible we may have to reauthenticate via LTI every time we need to transfer auth from LTI to Valence.  Does this sound right?

Comment: In any case, I do not see such behavior in my testing.  I still just get the login page, so I still don't know how the authentication from LTI to Valence needs to be done.  I do know that the normal interactive Valence auth process uses more than a single cookie, i.e.:
 
   name: TS762d5e
   value: c255dc00001065caab976d1e41d61a08384714e6b2e3248b4fc50ed1d807b6dbe8ee9af501ef1d671fdf93a73adcaa26ffffffff

   name: d2lSecureSessionVal
   value: OrXNCUzb8iHOLeduQUQ5Spp6g
 
   name: d2lSessionVal
   value: GSbgiWsPTtVSuUzthpiDaVpRq

Comment: These Valence auth cookies also use the same server domain and a path of "/", with no specified expiry. Is there an actual working example anywhere of LTI-Valence auth transfer?

I also find I cannot even login to Valence directly using a browser on our 9.4.1 server (after manually constructing the necessary login page request url and copying it to the address bar).  Is there a way to verify whether Valence functionality is in fact available?  Does the login I am using via LTI need a special privilege to use Valence services?

Comment: We have now tried this on a 10.x server, where we can successfully authenticate via LTI an Valence separately, and still the suggested procedure for LTI-Valence auth conversion does not work.  The same Valence login page gets returned as when no prior LTI auth has occurred or no session cookie is included.  Has anyone seen a working example of this?

Comment: Give me a couple days, I have some code like this and I will find a spot to host it.

Comment: Thanks for making the sample code available.  Unfortunately, it does not reveal the details of what must be done in our use case.  We can't redirect the tool request itself back to the server, we need to be able to authenticate from within the context of the tool request itself.

Comment: What we need is to be able to construct a request from scratch that includes all the necessary information to authenticate via Valence for a given user (typically the session user), given that we are running in the context of an existing tool request, and we have access to the tool request parameters and other session information, and we have successfully authenticated the user via BLTI, and we have access to all the information associated with that request and response, but we don't have the user's password.

Comment: The sample doesn't make it clear what part of the session information is needed by the Valence request in order to make the pass-through work.  This is what we need to know, so that we can construct the necessary request from scratch, just as we do with BLTI.  As with BLTI, surely there is some token that is passed or can be passed with the tool request that we can use to proceed with Valence authentication.  This is what we really need.

Comment: Within the context of an External Tool servicing a request, we need to call the 'Authenticate3' operation on the 'LTIAuthenticationTokenService', in order to be able to call other SOAP APIs on behalf of the session user.  We also need to be able to call Valence APIs on behalf of that same user, so we need to somehow authenticate via Valence as well, using the information associated with the tool request and/or the 'Authenticate3' call.

Comment: Redirecting the tool request back to the server isn't an option, because we are authenticating separately from the main tool request.  In the process of constructing the separate request, we can transfer whatever request parameters, session information, or BLTI information is necessary, but we need to know what that information is.

Comment: It would also work if there was a SOAP call to give us a Valence token, just as there is a Valence call to give us a SOAP token.  That would solve our problem too.  Is there such a call?  Is there any other way to get from a successful BLTI authentication to a successful Valence authentication without reprompting for credentials?

Comment: Can I suggest you restate your question with information on the particular D2LWS call you want to make, the particular valence call you want to make and timing relative to the LTI Launch?

Comment: Sure.  Numerical sequence follows:

1. LTI launch

2. Various things occur

Comment: 3. D2LWS call - there a number of these that occur at various times and under various conditrions, but the one we are concerned with here is the 'Authenticate3' operation on the 'LTIAuthenticationTokenService'.  We do this in order to obtain the authorization necessary to be able to call various other operations in various other D2LWS services.  This works great, because we get the necessary information from the LTI request parameters in order to be able to make this call, and the response provides us with the necessary token information for the session user we need to make other calls.

Comment: 4. Various things occur

5. Valence authentication - here we want to do something like we're doing in step 3 above, only for Valence instead of BLTI.  This is the part we need help with.

6. Various things occur

7. Valence call - this could be any Valence call that the session user is authorized to perform, but for the sake of concreteness assume it is a call to create a grade object using the "/d2l/api/le/{version}/{org unit id}/grades/" API.

Comment: Let me know how I can clarify things further.  We're comfortable with D2LWS and Valence calls, and low-level web programming in general.  We just need to be able to authenticate the session user without having their password, without prompting them for it, and without redirecting the LTI request.  We need to construct a request separate from the LTI request to obtain the Valence token information.  We know how to do this if we have the username and password, and we know how to do this if we can prompt the user for them, but not how to do this silently for the session user within an LTI launch.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. "authenticate the session without having their password, without prompting them for it and without redirecting". The answer to the previous is that "you can't". However, if the reason you don't want to redirect is strictly usability (i.e. you don't want to prompt for password) then you can achieve that usability with the redirect. So I guess the only clarification I need to help further is why you are designing to avoid the redirect or what the constraint on that is.

Comment: Since we can authenticate the session without a password, without prompting, and without redirecting when we use BLTI, we assumed this would also be possible with Valence.

Comment: We aren't designing to avoid the redirect, the design already exists and we are adding new code for Valence API support, so redesigning and reimplementing the overall LTI request flow would destabilize parts of the code that otherwise don't need to change.  The app is designed to service the main LTI request and be done, doing everything that is necessary within the context of that request, and secondary requests spawned from it.

Comment: With a redirect of the main LTI request, the external tool server will have to be modified to maintain the state of the original request, establish another endpoint for the D2L server to redirect back to, go through the Valence redirect process, and then restore the original state and process the initial request, all in order to simply authenticate the session user.

Comment: Another issue is that, after redirecting the main LTI request back to the server, if the pass-through fails, the user will be left with a screen that is either blank, shows a login page, or is whatever the D2L server provides, because the external tool server can't regain control until the final Valence redirect occurs, and it
won't occur unless the pass-through is successful.  Plus, the tool server will need to somehow detect that a previous redirect failed and discard any state saved for that request.

Comment: Our problem is only with a redirect of the main LTI request.  We can construct any kind of secondary http request we need, and support any kind of special redirect handling needed for that secondary request.  Everything else we need to do, both via the SOAP APIs and Valence APIs can be done within our existing request flow, without prompting, using separate secondary requests.  This includes BLTI authentication for the session user, since the LTI request passes what we need to make a call to obtain a token for that user.  It even includes Valence authentication, if we have the password.

Comment: Is there any way for the main LTI request to pass the information we need to proceed with Valence authentication of the session user, as it does now for BLTI authentication?  Alternatively, is there any way to go from a successful BLTI authentication to a Valence authentication, as there is now from a Valence authentication to a D2LWS authentication?

Comment: If neither of the above is possible, can we just copy session information (cookies, etc.) from the main LTI request to a secondary request for the Valence login page, and handle it that way?  We tried that with a standalone BLTI authentication, but it didn't work, so maybe it has to be an actual LTI launch.  If so, what session info should we copy from the main LTI request to the secondary request?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12259/discussion-between-cadmium-and-user1382547)